# How to bind the property to the selected node in the Treeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How to bind the custom property to the selected node's IsSelected property in MVVM,
I have loaded the nodes at runtime into the treeview. I am using MVVM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a small example:

```
public abstract class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Item>()
            {
                new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item1", IsSelected = false, Sample = "Sample: I am Item1"},
                new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item2", IsSelected = true, Sample = "Sample: I am Item2"},
                new Item() {DisplayValue = "Item3", IsSelected = false, Sample = "Sample: I am Item3"}
            };
        }
    }
}

public class Item : ViewModel
{
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    private bool _isSelected = false;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    private string _sample;

    public string Sample
    {
        get
        {
            return _sample;
        }
        set
        {
            _sample = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sample");
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication93.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication93"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <local:MyViewModel></local:MyViewModel>
    </Grid.DataContext>

    <StackPanel>
      <TreeView x:Name="myTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayValue}"></TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
              </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>

            <Style.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <!-- if you want to customize the appearance of a selected element do it here -->
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
              </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      </TreeView>

      <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myTreeView, Path=SelectedItem.Sample}"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `<TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">                    
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />                   
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>` I used the above code, and put breakpoint on the IsSelected set property. its not working.

Comment: Please have a look in the output window. Do you find any binding errors?
And is the getter working, ie. when you set one Treeviewitem to IsSelected=true, is it selected in the view?

Comment: I want to do some opertation,when i select a node in the treeview

Comment: Your sample code is working for Bold the selected item. but its not working for selectedItemChanged

Comment: Tanya, I pasted a MVVM sample.
There is no need for the SelectedItemChanged event, as the items get notified if they are selected via the "IsSelected" property.
This is also the point where you could execute your operation to do other stuff with the selected element.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6571/discussion-between-sveng-and-tanya)

Comment: I have created a property "Sample" in the MyViewModel Class and Set some value when the TreeView node get Selected. But its not reflecting in the Label property
<Label Uid="sampleLabel" Content="{Binding Sample,Mode=TwoWay}" /> The Sample property is an public proerty

Comment: When i tried to set value to the Sample property in the MyViewModel itself means that will reflected in Label. But when tried to set value in the Derived class "Item" is not reflecting in label. please give me an idea