# WPF Treeview IsSelected Binding

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have set up a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate.
I want to set the IsSelected property of a TreeViewItem by Binding so in my ViewModel I have a Property
"ObjectToSelectInTreeView" which holds the object.

In the TreeView I have a Style with multibinding

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Setter Property="IsSelected">
    <Setter.Value>
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IsSelectedConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
        <Binding ElementName="TreeViewControl" Path="DataContext.DocumentToSelectInTree"
          UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"></Binding>
        <Binding Path="."></Binding>
      </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsDeleted}" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And the Converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
 {
   ModelBase itemForComparison;
   if (values[0] != null)
   {
     if (values[1] is ObservableDocument)
       itemForComparison = ((ObservableDocument)values[1]).Document;
     else
       itemForComparison = (ModelBase)values[1];

     if (values[0] == itemForComparison)
       return true;
   }
 return false;
}
```

First time all works.
But when I manually select all items in TreeView and then set the ObjectToSelectInTreeView the converter will never run again and so no object is selected.

Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0):

`DataContext.DocumentToSelectInTree` property changed is going to trigger the calculation of `IsSelectedConverter` converter.

I hope you might have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface for your ViewModel.
Write the ItemSelectedCommand for the TreeView if you have not written already, and trigger the PropertyChanged Notification for `DocumentToSelectInTree` property whenever the `ItemSelected` is executed

Comment: Thanks for answer
The ViewModel implements the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
I've added a EventToCommand and whenever the SelectedItemChanged Event is fired, I set the ObjectToSelectInTree to the new Value and call " RaisePropertyChanged("ObjectToSelectInTree");"  but nothing changes. When I have selected all Objects in tree manually, the converter never fires

Comment: I think this approach with converter will not work. Did you check other ways to implement? - e.g. the way given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800479/how-to-bind-the-property-to-the-selected-node-in-the-treeview-in-wpf

Comment: hmm Problem is that my Model doesn't have an IsSelected Property and I can't change the model
temporarily it works with my approach because I use it for scanning and so the items are just selected one time by code but when I later want to select an item out of code I got a problem. 

Because of that I've hoped for a solution